# on click for asp:textbox?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Im looking for a way to have a textbox contain a bit of text until a users clicks into it to enter their own text.
Its a search field and the customer wants the textbox to have "Search Stock" in the textbox, then when a users clicks in it, it becomes null so they can enter their own criteria.
I cant see an onclick or similar in the designview for the textbox though, any hints?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" value="Search Stock" ID="textbox1"
             onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search Stock')  this.value = ''; "
             onblur="if (this.value == '')  this.value ='Search Stock'; " />
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called "placeholder text" - search for that, there are lots of examples (including built-in in html5)

Answer (score 0):

Pre populate the Text property of the TextBox with the value "Search Stock". Then use javascript, and on the OnClick client event of the TextBox...clear the Text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty version.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="overlayTextbox" runat="server"ForeColor="#A0ABC6" Text="Search Stock" onfocus="hidePlaceholder(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

and the script to hide the placehoder:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hidePlaceholder(sender) {
        var overlayHidden = sender.getAttribute('placeholderHidden');
        if (overlayHidden != '1') {
            sender.setAttribute('placeholderHidden', '1');
            sender.value = "";
            sender.style.color = "#000000";
        }
    }
</script>
```